# SQL Server 2008 restore option is disabled when database goes offline

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I can use query

```
RESTORE DATABASE @db_name 
FROM DISK = 'PATH_TO_BACKUP_FILE.BAK'
```

to do restore, but I just wonder why in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, the restore option is disabled once the database goes offline.

But in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, the restore option becomes enabled again.

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot backup a database that is offline.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx#Anchor_4)

Comment: but I have backup the database when it is online, and I set the database to go offline. Then I cannot restore it.

Comment: I want to know why I cannot restore the backup through the studio 2008 UI (I know I can do it with query). However, In studio 2014, I can do it with UI

Comment: There have been several enhancements made to the restore UI since 2008/R2.  Perhaps this is just one of them.  Are you trying to accomplish a task, or is your question based on curiosity?  In SQL 2008, I would just go through the manual steps of bringing db online, then restoring via SSMS GUI.  Otherwise, automate via a script - as you mentioned.